# Add HTML5 timecode into a textarea by button

Tags: javascript, html, video

In [this past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262145/passing-information-between-html-5-video-and-form-textarea), someone asked how to pass the currentTime property of an HTML5 video into a textarea. Rather than just displaying the current time, I would like to insert the current time into the textarea when a button is pressed. And be able to do this multiple times.

I create corporate videos, and I want to make a page where people can watch a preview of their video, and insert the current timecode in order to write comments on that part of the video.

Thank you.

Comment: You will have to show some code and show the part which you are having problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working example:

```js
var timeGetter = document.getElementById("timeGetter"),
    video = document.getElementById("video"),
    comment = document.getElementById("comment");

document.getElementById("timeGetter").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  comment.value = comment.value + "\n"+ video.currentTime;  
});
```

```html
<video src="https://vimeo-hp-videos.global.ssl.fastly.net/5/5-vp9.webm" id="video" autoplay width="200"></video>

<a href="#" id="timeGetter">Get current time!</a>
  
<textarea id="comment" rows="20"></textarea>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to have minutes and seconds instead of just seconds? e.g. 02:45

Comment: @Malcolm yes of course! you can do that with simple math, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3733257/2330145

Answer (score 0):

You can use much of the same code. Just make the event handler it's own function and call it using `oncilck` from the button:

```
function showTime() {
    var theText = document.getElementById('text1');
    var theVideo = document.getElementById('video1');
    curTime = theVideo.currentTime;
    curSecs = Math.floor((curTime % 60));

    curTimeText = "\n" + Math.floor( curTime / 60 ) + ":" + ((curSecs < 10)?'0'+curSecs:curSecs);

    theText.value = theText.value + curTimeText;
});
```

HTML:

```
<video width="100%" controls id="video1">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="">
</video>
<textarea id="text1" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea>
<button onclick="showTime()">Show current time</button>
```